# Java FX-2 Timer count increasing heap size

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, timeline

I am showing timer on user interface in a Java FX 2.0 application. Problem is that when i start a timer on the screen(showing it on label) it starts to increase HEAP size and that is increasing no of Survivors in GC, i checked all its behavior in NetBeans profiler. But when i stopped(i.e. comment) the timer code every thing was working perfectly. I am sharing my timer code if any one can suggest memory leak or any other timer showing procedure to save me from increasing Heap size. Here is my ShowTime code.

```
  public void startTimer(){
    timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
            new EventHandler() {
        // KeyFrame event handler
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {

         //   System.out.println("Entring time event");
            if (timeSeconds % 60 == 0) {
                mm++;
            }

            pagingTimeLbl.setText(String.format("%02d", mm) + " : " + String.format("%02d", timeSeconds % 60));
            if(paging.getPriority()){
                pagingPanelGrid.setStyle(timeSeconds%2==0?"-fx-border: 2px solid; -fx-border-color: red;":"-fx-border: 2px solid; -fx-border-color: black;");
            }

            if (timeSeconds <= 0) {
                timeline.stop();
            }
            timeSeconds++;
        }
    }));
    timeline.playFromStart();
}
```

Comment: The possible sources are: String.format which creates a temporary string and the setStyle method. The former should not create any issues. I don't know how the latter is implemented - you could try removing the setStyle line to see if it makes a difference

Comment: Tried by did't find any luck.

Comment: You should use a profiler (jProfiler for example) to see what objects are being created.